# Android : Show quick preview (live) before exporting FFmpeg Video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

Basically, I am developing a video editing app that lets the user choose some of their images and create a video slide show with music.

I am using *FFMPEG* to generate video slide show from images but the problem is I can only show the preview of the video after executing *FFMPEG* command.

Is googled so many blogs and all and I know there is a possible way available to display the preview of the output.

Check below image from reference app. I am developing something similar to this app. There is an option to replace the image in the video. This app displays instant preview once I change the image.

[image]

Here is the link of the [reference app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.newbiz.mvmaster) if anyone wants to check:

Clicking an EXPORT button this app lets you generate a video output. I can do that as I know *FFMPEG* and how to generate OUTPUT FILE using *FFMPEG* but what I don't know is **how to display a quick preview of OUTPUT VIDEO before generating actual VIDEO FILE.**

On my UBUNTU device, I can view the output of *FFMPEG* command using *FFPLAY* tool but how to do the same on android device.

Some useful link:
http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

Comment: Hey akash, Did you get any solution?

Comment: Not yet! @PratikButani

Comment: have you tried to decompile the reference app com.newbiz.mvmaster, to see what they are actually doing?

Comment: video link which is created by my app:  https://www25.zippyshare.com/v/JCMwOZnB/file.html

Answer (score 2):

I installed the reference app, and it looks like they are not actually exporting video when showing preview.

After taking the image, they divide it into 16 parts and animating the image view and playing audio simultaneously

and when you click export then they are actually saving the video.

check this lib for image animation : https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView

or this one : https://github.com/florent37/ViewAnimator

Answer (score 1):

i read all comments and got that ur looking for ffmpeg command that get 2 to 3 images a input and one alpha rgb video for effect which is used by MV Master app i have made ffmpeg command using ffmpeg documentation and got desired out put as MV Master App Do. cheack out below out put and let me know if your are looking for same will share code if u need

https://www25.zippyshare.com/v/JCMwOZnB/file.html

https://www111.zippyshare.com/v/LQzuZtPe/file.html

actually video you got from MV Master app is RGB + ALPHA Video which is used to create MV video effects. you got both video in one video . both video has black color so by using ffmpeg we have to pass black color code to ffmpeg command. ffmpeg will use that black color as transperent area and after that we have to overlay that video to image

Comment: Can we use any plugin or software to generate those commands?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffplay to display it example:-

```
ffplay test.mp4 -af "volume=8.0,atempo=4.0" -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,setpts=1/4*PTS,scale=640*480" -aspect 4:2
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ffplay for it.

Tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5ALCIxKZIE

example : 
ffplay -f mpegts -ast 1 -vst 0 -ar 48000 udp://192.168.0.114:8090

Detail Article how to deal with Android Multi Video over Andriod :
http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

To do you have to link your video player with on port 8090, you can show it on play and pause result on it.

Comment: Thanks for your response on this but i want to play video on android and not on my PC. I know FFPLAY helps to preview the output on desktop but how do the same on android app? if you can help i will pay you for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do following way:

- Select image
- Check whether having 2 or more images?
- If its more than 2 images, Export particular video in background without disturbing user (on constant path which will be user for every video)
- Show as preview, give `ProgressBar` if user getting stuck.

Advice for more user experience: Give checkbox option **Show Instant Preview**

Note : You can also put this type of work on fiverr or other freelancing websites.

Thank you.